# DataGridView row index always returns the same value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to implement DeleteItem functionality on my DataGridView.
I have the following event:

```
private void btnDeleteDjelatnik_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int idDjelatnik = -1;
    int index = djelatnikDataGrid.CurrentRow.Index;
    Int32.TryParse(djelatnikDataGrid.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), out idDjelatnik);
    r.DeleteDjelatnik(idDjelatnik);
}
```

I'm trying to get selected rows ID Column so I can pass it to my Delete method: DeleteDjelatnik(int slectedID);

the following line always gives me value of 3:

```
int index = djelatnikDataGrid.CurrentRow.Index;
```

I also tried

```
int index = djelatnikDataGrid.SelectedRows[0].Index;
```

but I'm getting ArgumentOutOfRange exception, yes my SelectionMode is on FullRowSelect

How to get this to work?

Comment: try datagridview.CurrentCell.RowIndex

Comment: The `CurrentRow` and `SelectedRow` may not be same. `CurrentRow` will returns a row that cell is active. The `SelectedRows` returns the selection, so you should be using `djelatnikDataGrid.SelectedRows[0]`.

Comment: I already tried datagridview.CurrentCell.RowIndex and I still get value 3 no matter what row I pick :/

Comment: as I said  int index = djelatnikDataGrid.SelectedRows[0].Index; throws ArgumentOutOfRange exception

Comment: That clearly indicates you don't have any rows selected.

Comment: if `djelatnikDataGrid.SelectedRows[0]...` throws ArgumentOutOfRange, either you have no row selected before clicking the button or the `SelectionMode`is not what it should be

Comment: I do select the row and my SelectionMode is on FullRowSelect as it should be

Comment: Sorry, but I can't believe it :) Can you debug your code,set a breakpoint in your click event and check the value of `djelatnikDataGrid.SelectionMode` and `djelatnikDataGrid.SelectedRows.Count` at that point?

Comment: Count is 0, but why??? I select the row every time

Comment: I put the MultiSelect from false to true and now I get djelatnikDataGrid.SelectedRows.Count = 1

Comment: but int index = djelatnikDataGrid.SelectedRows[0].Index; still returns the same value?!?!?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem was DeleteItem property in my BindingNavigator!

Before I set it to "None" it would delete the row from my DataGridView before the execution of "btnDeleteDjelatnik_Click" and mess up the indexation so I couldn't get the real ID of the row I wanted to delete!

My method now looks like this:

```
private void btnDeleteDjelatnik_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = djelatnikDataGrid.SelectedRows[0].Index;
    int idDjelatnik = -1;
    Int32.TryParse(djelatnikDataGrid["IDDjelatnik", index].Value.ToString(), out idDjelatnik);
    r.DeleteDjelatnik(idDjelatnik);
    djelatnikDataGrid.Rows.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

Thanks for help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Use DataGridView's `UserDeletingRow` event,

```
 private void dataGridView1_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
        {
           int deletingRowIndex = e.Row.Index;
        }
```

Hope helps,

Comment: oh snap, I think I just figured out why I'm getting errors... In my DataGridView the item I try to delete gets deleted beforehand (since I used BindingNavigator) and then my RowIndex changes to -1, then when I call my method to delete from database i delete wrong item (the one with index -1)...

Comment: I will definitely use this method to get the index before the item actually gets deleted, that's where my whole confusion begun xD

Comment: @ChenChi Glad to hear that helped :)

Comment: It turns out that UserDeletingRow didn't fire, since I had DeleteItem property set to different method in my BindingNavigator... after I set DeleteItem property to "None" I used my original event "btnDeleteDjelatnik_Click" without problem. The Real Problem was DeleteItem property on my BindingNavigator (it deleted the row I tried to get index of so it messed up indexation of rows)... so I have to unmark this answer as solution

Comment: Please post your whole code related to this problem. @ChenChi

Comment: I just wrote another answer - hope it makes sense

Comment: In this situation, don't add new answers, just update your question. @ChenChi

Answer (score 0):

Since DataGridView Index property doesn't return correct value I wrote this piece of code:

```
public int djelatnikSelectedRowIndex { get; set; }

private void djelatnikDataGrid_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    djelatnikSelectedRowIndex = e.RowIndex;
}
```

Comment: Well..`SelectedRows[i].Index` has never failed to me,never... :)

Comment: that doesn't help me lol xD, it seems like something really weird is going on in the background

Comment: If I find out some additional information why this is happening I will post it

Comment: @Pikoh SelectedRows[i].Index works fine now! I figured it all out... the real problem was DeleteItem property in my BindingNavigator since it deleted the row on index I selected before the actual execution of my "btnDeleteDjelatnik_Click" event - so it messed up the indexation of rows!!

Comment: Ok, it was obvious something wrong was in another place as `SelectedRows` should always return the right one. Glad you figured it out :)